# How to pick the localization strings for the specific Blazor-component from resource files in the same directory as target Blazor component?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I don't want to move the resources files `TasksManagementPage.en.resx` and `TasksManagementPage.ja.resx` to the `resources` directory - let these files be organized in the same directory as other files of the `TaskManagemenetPageContent` component.

[image]

**Target**

All static strings inside the `TasksManagementPageContent` component (both Blazor template part and logic part) must be picked from the resources files `TasksManagementPage.en.resx` or `TasksManagementPage.ja.resx`.

**Initial code**

The template part of `TasksManagementPageContent` component:

```xml
<TaskManager 
  onInputtingDataOfNewTaskComplete=@onNewTaskEditingCompleted
  @ref=@taskManager
/>

<ModalDialog
  title=StaticStrings["FilteringModalDialog-Title"]
  onInitializedEventCallback=@onTasksFilteringModalDialogInitialized
>
  <TasksFilteringPanel />
</ModalDialog>
```

The logic part of `TasksManagementPageContent` component:

```cs
public partial class TasksManagementPageContent : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase
{
    private readonly StaticStrings = /* Retrieve it somehow from resources files. */

    private TaskManager taskManager = null!;
  
    private void beginInputOfNewTaskData()
    {
        this.taskManager.beginInputNewTaskData();
    }
  
    private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task onNewTaskEditingCompleted(CommonSolution.Gateways.ITaskGateway.Adding.RequestData requestData)
    {
        BlockingLoadingOverlayService.displayBlockingLoadingOverlay();

        try
        {
            await TasksSharedState.addTask(requestData);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _ = SnackbarService.displaySnackbarForAWhile(
            message: this.StaticStrings["Snackbar-TaskAddingFailed"],
        decorativeVariation: Snackbar.StandardDecorativeVariations.error
            );

            Debug.WriteLine(exception);
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            BlockingLoadingOverlayService.dismissBlockingLoadingOverlay();  
        }

        this.taskManager.utilizeTaskEditing();
    
        _ = SnackbarService.displaySnackbarForAWhile(message: this.StaticStrings["Snackbar-TaskHasBeenAdded"], decorativeVariation: Snackbar.StandardDecorativeVariations.success);
    }
}
```

Resource file example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <!-- ... -->
  <data name="FilteringModalDialog-Title" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Filter tasks</value>
  </data>
  <data name="Snackbar-TaskAddingFailed" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>The malfunction has occurred during adding of new task.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="Snackbar-TaskHasBeenAdded" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>The task has been added.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="Snackbar-TaskChangesSavingError" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>The malfunction has occurred during the saving of changes.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="Snackbar-TaskChangesSavingSuccess" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>The task has been updated.</value>
  </data>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
[Inject]
protected IStringLocalizer<TasksManagementPageContent> Loc { get; set; } = default!;
```

A minimal example:

```
public partial class Home: ComponentBase
{
    [Inject]
    protected IStringLocalizer<Home> Loc { get; set; } = default!;
    private  string? Hello => Loc["Hello"];
}
```

in Razor Component:

```
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>


<h2>@Hello</h2>

Welcome to your new app.
```

resource file:

[image]

in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddLocalization();
.....
var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-US", "es-CL" };
var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
    .SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
    .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
    .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);

app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am sorry, would you please tell me how the `Home` class knows from which file resources must be taken? It should be some way to set the path to resources files.

Comment: If you want to move the resource files to another folder(Resources),you could set the path with:builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

Comment: If you don't set the path,it would load resource files in the same directory with your .cs file

Comment: And the document related with Resource file naming may help:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization/provide-resources?view=aspnetcore-8.0#resource-file-naming